# Avoid cost of volatile value in AtomicReference

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Thread 1 -> Compute a value `MyObject` and store in `AtomicReference< MyObject>>`

Thread 2 -> Would sometimes need the value of `MyObject` stored by Thread 1

Looking at `AtomicReference::set` the value set in `volatile` field.

Since Thread 2 would only need the value sometimes does it help in performance if from Thread 1 it is instead set as `AtomicReference<Supplier< MyObject >>`?

Comment: What have you measured as the overhead?  How much faster does your program run with the alternative, less-clear formulation?  And why not just use an AtomicInteger?

Comment: I would have thought is would be *slower* ... since thread 1 now needs to generate function references and thread 2 needs to call `accept` to get the value.  But this smells like *premature optimization*.

Comment: I'd also assume that the `Supplier` is now stored in a `volatile` reference, meaning the idea that started this optimization has in fact not gone anywhere.

Comment: You do not need an `AtomicReference`, just access `MyObject` directly in a volatile field and you are fine

Comment: Some things are unclear. 1. Does thread 1 calculate exactly one value or new values repeatedly? 2. What does “sometimes” mean in this context? From time to time (multiple times during the thread’s lifetime but with large time in-between) or just “once or never” in one runtime? 3. How does thread 2 ensure that thread 1 has completed the calculation by the time it needs the value (for the first time)?